# Facebook Graph API get page_impressions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've been using the graph api to get insights for our page. I log in, authorise and get a page access token. Recently, Facebook made it impossible to get any data without getting your app reviewed. I've managed to get my app reviewed with the following permissions:

> manage_pages, email, read_insights, default: 
>   These are found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

This is my call:
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/insights/page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique

And this is the response:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": 
"https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/300196376675661/insights?access_token=xxx&pretty=0&metric=page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique&since=1532674800&until=1532847600",
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/300196376675661/insights?access_token=xxx&pretty=0&metric=page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique&since=1533020400&until=1533193200"
  }
}
```

Are there additional permissions that I need to get in my app? Has anyone managed to get these insights?

Looking for these items:

```
[
("page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique", "day"),
("page_impressions", "day"), ("page_impressions_unique", "day"),
("page_impressions_paid", "day"),
("page_views_by_age_gender_logged_in_unique", "day")
]
```

Comment: Does your page have sufficient likes to have Insights generated for it?
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10209870960357654

Comment: This may be the issue. Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

This might help!

Your query should be like this => 
`"<your_page_id>/insights?metric=page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique&accessToken=<your_page_access_token>"`

Make sure to pass the Page Access Token, not user token.